# Full text search in mongodb in .net

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have to search contents in all documents in particular collection of mongodb in .net mvc . I have tried with mongodb shell by creating index successfully like here .

```
db.collection_name.createIndex( { subject: "text" } )

db.collection_name.find( { $text: { $search: "search_word" } } )
```

It works fine . but when i put it in .net that gives me error . I googled it and got following solution for indexing .

```
 collection.EnsureIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder().Ascending("subject"));
```

now how can i run this query `db.collection_name.find( { $text: { $search: "coffee" } } )` .

I am trying in .net as following way .

```
collection.CreateIndex("subject":"text");

var query = collection.Find({ $text: { $search: "coffe" }});
```

but I am getting error on first line "represents text as series of unicode ....syntax error "

2nd line error "There is no argument given that corresponds to required formal parameters " And "unexpected character $ ".

any suggestion will be appreciated .

Comment: You need to show the .NET code and when you say it "gives error" - what error?

Comment: var collection = Database.GetCollection<searchFileByAuthor>("articles");
 collection.EnsureIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder().Ascending("subject"));
 var query  = collection.find( { $text: { $search: "coffee" } } );

Comment: error in last line i think we can not write query directly as we write in mongodb shell . so i have to get the solution for .net to full text search in mongodb

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I could create text indexes with this command:

```
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(Builders<searchFileByAuthor>.IndexKeys.Text(x=>x.subject));
```

And than i could query index this way:

```
collection.Find(Builders<searchFileByAuthor>.Filter.Text("coffe")).ToList();
```

`searchFileByAuthor` is just my fake class with subject field:

```
public class searchFileByAuthor
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string subject { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I tried it but getting error . "Argument 1: can not convert from 'MongoDb.Driver.Filter.Definition<TDocument>' ...to 'MongoDb.Driver.IMongoQuery' .

Comment: what is exactly commant you are trying to execute? I have updated my answer.

Comment: thanks.  I want just search within file or documents . and this query i want to execute  ..                                                                              collection.CreateIndex(subject:"text");
var query = collection.Find({ $text: { $search: "coffe" }});

Comment: I have run this query but there is error on indexes . I am sure i have subject field in my model class (e.g searchFileByAuthor) as you described here . but error cursor on indexes saying "MongoCollection<searchFileByAuthor>" does not contain a definition for 'indexes' and no extention method  'indexes' accepting first argument of MongoCollection<searchFileByAuthor> could be found . <are you missing directive or assembly reference>

Comment: What version of mongo c# driver do you use and what is a version of your mongodb? I use mongo driver 2.4.0 and  mongodb version 3.4

Comment: mongodb version is 3.4

Comment: and mongodb driver version is 2.4.0

Comment: are you sure , that your syntax is the sam as mine? It should look like: collection.Indexes.CreateOne(Builders<searchFileByAuthor>.IndexKeys.Text(x=>x.subject)); with capital I o "Indexes", your exception message is talking about "indexes" with small "i"

Comment: I am sure , I am running same as you said . and my model is also same as yours . I am copying your code so there is I "Index" is already capital . and I wrote samll "i" in exception .

Comment: I have less than 50 reputation so i can not live chat yet . :)

Comment: I don't really know, what the problem could be. This property is in Mongo c# driver since version 2.3  https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_Indexes.htm

Comment: should i reinstall c# mongo driver ?

Comment: I am getting my collection in this way . is it correct         .  .  .  .   var collection = Database.GetCollection<searchFileByAuthor>("articles");

Comment: Yes, it's right, check the version of your c# driver.  I mean the version that you see in nuget manager tool in visual studio.

Comment: I have checked again and changed mongodb's parent instance from public MongoDatabase Database to ' IMongoDatabase ' , and that indexes errors gone but there is more issue now in connection . Database  = server.getDatabase("dbname");

Comment: there is issue like this cannot convert type from MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabase to MongoDB.Driver.IMongoDatabase . an explicit conversion exists.

Comment: o thanks worked for me by Implementing Interface IMongoDB  . great

Answer (score 14):

Maksim Simkin answer is correct, althought it is obsolete.
The updated version would be:

```
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(new CreateIndexModel<YourClass>(Builders<YourClass>.IndexKeys.Text(x => x.something)));
```

or, if you would like to use the **Wildcard Indexing** (to index the entire document), you could do like this:

```
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(new CreateIndexModel<YourClass>(Builders<YourClass>.IndexKeys.Text("$**")));
```

or maybe you want/have more indexes for some reason, than do this:

```
var indexWildcardTextSearch = new CreateIndexModel<YourClass>(Builders<YourClass>.IndexKeys.Text("$**"));

List<CreateIndexModel<YourClass>> indexes = new List<CreateIndexModel<YourClass>>();
indexes.Add(indexWildcardTextSearch);

collection.Indexes.CreateMany(indexes);
```

And to query, it remains the same:

```
collection.Find(Builders<YourClass>.Filter.Text("something")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<T> FindSearch<T>(string collectionName, string searchWord) {
    IMongoQuery query = Query.Text(searchWord);
    List<T> find = getCollection<T>(collectionName).Find(query).ToList();
    return find;
}
```