# MongoDB text search using c# Driver 2.4.4

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using MongoDB in c#. To search a 'question' in the 'knowledge' collection, this is my code.

```
 var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("knowledge");
 var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("question", question);
 var results = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Instead of this I want to search a 'question' that contains the given words. I want to search a pattern simply like following in MongoDB.

```
 db.stores.find( { $text: { $search: "java \"coffee shop\"" } } )
```

I found this in the Stack.

```
  collection.Indexes.CreateOne(Builders<searchFileByAuthor>.IndexKeys.Text(x=>x.subject));
 collection.Find(Builders<searchFileByAuthor>.Filter.Text("coffe")).ToList();
```

[Full text search in mongodb in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356544/full-text-search-in-mongodb-in-net)

I am not familiar with using MongoDB in c# though. How should I modify my code to create a text index and search a pattern? How to do this in MongoDB .NET Driver version 2.4.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create search patterns you can use the Regex builder. Example to match either "java" or "coffee shop" in the description field:

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("knowledge");
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Regex("description", "(java)") | builder.Regex("description", "(coffee shop)");
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks. But when I have to search through a large collection will this slow down the performance? (compared to searching with text indexes)

Answer (score 2):

you can using full-text search

```
Collection.Indexes.CreateOne(new CreateIndexModel<T>(Builders<T>.IndexKeys.Text("$**")));
```

//build filter and query

```
var key = txtSearchKey.Text.ToLower().Trim();
var filter = Builders<EntityObject>.Filter.Text(key);
```