# Filtering using AsQueryable in Mongodb C# - ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to query the mongodb database using AsQueryable and LINQ functions.

My current database structure is that I have some collections, mainly a record which are defined in C# like this:

```
public class Record  
    {
        [BsonElement("formName")]
        public string FormName { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("created")]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("createdBy")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [BsonId]
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        private string InternalId { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("recordId")]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("recordId")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("organisationId")]
        public string OrganisationId { get; set; }

        // TODO: Consider making configurable
        private string appName = "MediLog";

        [BsonElement("appName")]
        public string AppName
        {
            get { return this.appName; }
            set { this.appName = value; }
        }

        [BsonElement("schemaVersion")]
        public int SchemaVersion { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("contents")]
        public ExpandoObject Contents { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("modified")]
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("modifiedBy")]
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("majorVersion")]
        public int MajorVersion { get; private set; }

        [BsonElement("minorVersion")]
        public int MinorVersion { get; private set; }

        [BsonElement("version")]
        public string Version
        {
            get
            {
                return (MajorVersion + "." + MinorVersion);
            }

            set
            {
                MajorVersion = Convert.ToInt32(value?.Substring(0, value.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                MinorVersion = Convert.ToInt32(value?.Substring(value.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + 1), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }

    }
```

As you, data are mainly stored in `Contents` which is an `ExpandoObject` and that's where my issue is.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
 var collection =
                database.GetCollection<Record>("recordData").AsQueryable()
                    .Where(x =>  x.Contents.SingleOrDefault(z => z.Key == "dateOfBirth").Value.ToString().Length > 0)
                        .ToList();
```

but I get this exception:

System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message={document}{contents}.SingleOrDefault(z => (z.Key == "dateOfBirth")).Value.ToString().Length is not supported.

Also, when I tried:

```
  var collection1 = database.GetCollection<Record>("recordData").AsQueryable()
                .Where(x => (DateTime)(x.Contents.SingleOrDefault(z => z.Key == "dateOfBirth").Value)  > DateTime.Now)
                .ToList();
```

I get this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Convert({document}{contents}.SingleOrDefault(z => (z.Key == "dateOfBirth")).Value) is not supported.
```

Also, when I do this:

```
var collection =
database.GetCollection(“recordData”).AsQueryable()
.Where(x => (DateTime)x.Contents.First(z => z.Key == “dateOfBirth”).Value > DateTime.Now ).ToList();
```

I am getting this exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: ‘The expression tree is not supported: {document}{contents}’
```

So my question really is that how can I run queries on an object which is of type ExpandoObject using AsQueryable and LINQ.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you're trying to pass into `.Where()` method is an expression tree that needs to be translated into MongoDB query language. C# compiler will accept `ExpandoObject`'s methods like `SingleOrDefault` (extension method) but this will fail in the runtime when such expression tree needs to be translated into Mongo query.

There's nothing special about `ExpandoObject` when you work with MongoDB. It has to be translated somehow into BSON document (MongoDB format) and for example below code:

```
dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();
o.dateOfBith = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
r.Contents = o;
col.InsertOne(r);
```

inserts `ExpandoObject` same way as `BsonDocument` or `Dictionary<string, T>` so it simply becomes:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId(",,,"), "contents" : { "dateOfBith" : ISODate("2000-01-01T07:00:00Z") } }
```

in your database.

Knowing that you can build your query using [the dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#embedded-documents). There's also a `StringFieldDefinition` class you can utilize since you cannot build an expression tree from `ExpandoObject` in a strongly typed way:

```
var fieldDef = new StringFieldDefinition<Record, DateTime>("contents.dateOfBith");
var filter = Builders<Record>.Filter.Gt(fieldDef, new DateTime(2000, 1, 1));

var res = col.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

These kind of Expression transformations doesn't play well with LINQ how I see. Tho if you go down 1 level to define the Field as string, it will play better. Than you can `Inject` your `Where` clause to keep `IQueryable` if you like>

**Update (you can have multiple conditions, and different kinds of null checking)**

```
string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
var records = db.GetCollection<Record>("recordData");
//dynamic content = new ExpandoObject();
//content.dateOfBirth = DateTime.Today;
//records.InsertOne(new Record
//{
//    AppName = "my app", Created = DateTime.Today, CreatedBy = "some user", FormName = "form name",
//    OrganisationId = "organization id", SchemaVersion = 1, Version = "1.1", Contents = content
//});
// first option for multiple conditions:
var filter =
    Builders<Record>.Filter.Lt("contents.dateOfBirth", DateTime.Now) &
    Builders<Record>.Filter.Gt("contents.dateOfBirth", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10)) &
    // checking if the field is there. Whether the value is null or not.
    Builders<Record>.Filter.Exists("contents.dateOfBirth") &
    // checking if the field is there, and it's not null
    Builders<Record>.Filter.Ne("contents.dateOfBirth", BsonNull.Value);
// second option for multiple conditions
var dateOfBirths = records.AsQueryable().Where(_ => filter.Inject()).Where(x => x.AppName == "my app").ToList();
```

from there, you can continue your `IQueryable` syntax.

**Update 2**

In case of `.Where(x => x.AppName.Contains("app"))` you'll get

```
"pipeline" : [
        {
            "$match" : {
                "contents.dateOfBirth" : {
                    "$exists" : true,
                    "$gt" : ISODate("2020-05-15T12:48:14.483+02:00"),
                    "$lt" : ISODate("2020-05-25T12:48:14.480+02:00"),
                    "$ne" : null
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$match" : {
                "appName" : /app/g
            }
        }
    ]
```

from profiling the database. So the `<string>.Contains(<string>)` is implemented in `IQueryable` as a regular expression filter not in memory.

Comment: The best answer so far! Can I also check for null? Also, is there a way to combine multiple conditions together?

Comment: @AmirNo-Family looks like you can. Keep in mind, that mongo is dynamic, so the definition of something is "null" can mean that the column even exists or not, or the value of the field is `BsonNull.Value`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! It pretty much answered my question and I understand there are some of the rules I have to follow such as Gt, Lt, Ne, etc. One last thing: Is there a way to check if a string field such as firstName contains a search phrase (case insensitive)? thank you!

Comment: You'll need a Text index on the field, than you can use (this answer)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357957/1859959] to use in the `&` chain. `Filter.Text...`. That is quiet handy, because you can specify language, text, diacritic sensitivity

Comment: On this bit, can I have Where(x => x.AppName.Contains("my app"))? Is this part executed as a query or on the application level (memory and .NET)?

Comment: I can check this out on monday. I have to gather profile-fu for that.

Comment: Till than, this two articles claim that it's db side regex queries `Where(... Contains`. https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver.html, http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/12/11/insenstive-search-with-mongo-with-c-and-linq-provider/

Comment: @AmirNo-Family profiling the `Contains` was not trivial. The shell throws `Error: SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag s` NoSQLBooster tool helped to see the results. Check out the update 2.