# How to convert whole Bson document to a string in dotnet

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am using cosmos DB with Mongo API (MongoClient). I need to check a value contains in any of the fields in a document that has more than 50 properties.

So, I am trying to convert the whole document to string and then checking with contains method like below.

```cs
var d = _client.Find(f => f.ToString().Contains(str)).Limit(10).ToList();
```

> 'Unsupported filter: {document}.ToString().Contains("MyStringHere").

How can I convert the whole document to string and then use `Contains` method on it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356544/full-text-search-in-mongodb-in-net/41357957 this question seems very similar to your problem

Comment: When I follow the link `Command find failed: $text not supported.`

Comment: how does your query look like? Did you create indexes, as there are on the link?

Comment: Same error while trying to create index also @fbede

Answer (score 0):

Using **MongoDB.Bson.BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson**, can convert Bson Document into a JSON formatted string.

```
string json = MongoDB.Bson.BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson<BsonDocument>(document);
```

Comment: But he isn't just trying to retrieve a document in json format, he is trying to search in all documents.

Comment: Yes @fbede 's understanding is correct.

Comment: maybe you are looking for [Builders](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/definitions/)