# Find method using Full-Text search to be case and diacritic insensitive

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, full-text-search

Using the MongoDB driver for the .NET framework, I need to develop a way of creating a full-text search method that ignores string cases and diacritics.

I've already tried using a regex expression for that, but it does not work for strings that have accents and weird casings (diacritics).

```
var filterDefinition = new BsonDocument("$expr", new BsonDocument("$regexMatch", new BsonDocument
{
   { "input", new BsonDocument("$toString", "$field") },
   { "regex", searchTerm },
   { "options", "i" }
}));
```

If I create a text index that ignores the diacritics, the full-text search method doesn't work.

```
db.BsonDocument.createIndex({name: 'text'},{default_language: 'pt'})
```

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Text(searchTerm);
```

Is there any way of combining these two approaches into something that meets the desired criteria?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356544/full-text-search-in-mongodb-in-net

Comment: Not really, all it does is help create the index. After that I would need to know to to implement a full-text search method. i.e: have a document with the name field as 'John', look for 'Jo' and retrieve that document.

Comment: The accepted answer shows a sample query, does that not work?